# Bind the properties of a form generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I bind the properties of a form that is generated dynamically?

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="col in colInfo">

    <template v-if="col.Type == 'text'">
       <label class="badge badge-info">{{col.Field}}</label>
       <textarea class="form-control form-control-md" rows="3" v-on:change="updateInsertMap(col.Field)"></textarea>
    </template>

    <template v-else>
       <label class="badge badge-info">{{col.Field}}</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" v:on:change="updateInsertMap(col.Field)">
    </template>

</div>
```

When the submit button is clicked, I need to get all the values before sending it to the server. How could I keep track of the values?

Comment: What does `updateInsertMap` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out! There is actually a clever way to achieve this.

We need to define a data property that will be an empty `object`. So the point is to bind this object to the form. The key in the object could be `id`, `name` or any key that helps the purpose of identification and the value will automatically become the value of the field.

Here is the example:

```
<template v-if="table.length > 0 && colInfo.length > 0">

 <div class="form-group" v-for="col in colInfo">
    <template v-if="col.Type == 'text'">
        <label class="badge badge-info">{{col.Field}}</label>
        <textarea class="form-control form-control-md" rows="3" v-model="insertMap[col.Field]"></textarea>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
        <label class="badge badge-info">{{col.Field}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" v-model="insertMap[col.Field]">
    </template>
 </div>

</template>
```

In the above example, `insertMap` is the object that is a binding property for this form. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `v-model` instead.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    colInfo: [
      {Type: 'input', Field: 'First Name', Value: 'John' },
      {Type: 'input', Field: 'Last Name', Value: 'Doe' },
      {Type: 'text', Field: 'Comment', Value: '3141592653589793238462643383279502' }
    ],
    dataToBeSent: undefined
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.dataToBeSent = this.colInfo.map((col) => col.Value)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="form-group" v-for="col in colInfo">

    <template v-if="col.Type == 'text'">
      <label class="badge badge-info">{{col.Field}}</label>
      <textarea 
        class="form-control form-control-md" 
        rows="3" 
        v-model="col.Value">
      </textarea>
    </template>

    <template v-else>
      <label class="badge badge-info">{{col.Field}}</label>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control form-control-md" 
        v-model="col.Value">
    </template>
    
    
  </div>
  <button v-on:click="submit()">Submit</button>
  <div>
    <h3>colInfo</h3>
    <div>{{colInfo}}</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Submitted Item</h3>
    <div>{{dataToBeSent}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```